# ¿Cómo borrar el último caracter de un textBox después de una longitud determinada en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, substring, textbox

estoy intentando borrar los caracteres que se digiten en un textBox luego de que su longitud sea igual a 10, pero cuando se cumple esta condición estos nuevos caracteres reemplazan las primeras letras del texto. ejemplo
1234567890  -si digito 5 otro número este va a reemplazar el , así:
5234567890

código:

```
private void materialSingleLineTextField2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

       if (txtName.Text.Length > 10)
        {
            String texto = txtName.Text;
            texto = texto.Substring(0, texto.Count() - 1);
            txtName.Text = texto;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yo en lugar de usar el evento keypress, utilizaría el keyup, así, cuando entra a tal evento, ya aparece el último dígito que has escrito.

Aquí te pongo como me funciona a mí la funcionalidad que quieres. Además, te indico como poner el cursor al final del texto del textbox cuando va borrando el último carácter, para que no te escriba al principio. Espero que te sirva.

```
private void txtName_keyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtName.Text.Length > 10) {
            txtName.Text = txtName.Text.Substring(0, 10);
            txtName.Select(txtName.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternativamente puedes usar la propiedad `MaxLength` de un textbox y ponerla en 10 lo que ignorara cualquier caracter introducido despues de que la cuenta llegue a 10

```
txtName.MaxLength = 10;
```

[Documentacion de Microsoft sobre propiedad MaxLength](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength?view=netframework-4.7.2)